# Need to understand the use of super._mint in this 721 token contract

Tags: solidity

In this ERC721 [implementation](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token-enumerable.sol) by 0xcert there is this _mint function:

```
function _mint(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) internal override virtual {
    super._mint(_to, _tokenId);
    tokens.push(_tokenId);
    idToIndex[_tokenId] = tokens.length - 1;
}
```

I need to understand the use of super._mint here, what is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the Solidity 0.6.2 docs:

> super: the contract one level higher in the inheritance hierarchy

That means `super._mint(_to, _tokenId);` in your code is actually pointing to method `_mint()` in contract `NFToken` which is located in file `nf-token.sol`. At the top of your smart contract you are importing that file like this `import "./nf-token.sol";`.

Answer (score 1):

The contract that you've linked in your question starts with:

```
contract NFTokenEnumerable is
  NFToken,
  ERC721Enumerable
{
```

Which means that `super._mint(_to, _tokenId)` calls function `mint` of either contract `NFToken` or contract `ERC721Enumerable`. A short search in that GitHub repo reveals that this function is in contract `NFToken`.

It's an internal function-call of course, because `NFTokenEnumerable` IS a (rather than HAS a) `NFToken`, i.e., no jump to another contract's code.